# Codeigniter IFNULL in set() mysql activerecord

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

There is a column abc in a table xyz, whose datatype is int and the default value is null. We assume that a particular row exists in the table in which the value of the field abc is null.

I wish to change abc to 'its previous value + some other value' by running a query multiple times. The issue comes when updating the column first time since its value is null.

Adding null to anything returns null, so this doesn't work:

`$this->db->set('abc', $value);`

I tried using this instead:

`$this->db->set('abc', "IFNULL(`abc`, 0) + $value");`

But this produces:

`UPDATE`xyz`SET`abc`= 'IFNULL(`abc`, 0) + value'`

But the required query is :

`UPDATE`xyz`SET`abc`= IFNULL(`abc`, 0) + value`
(without the inverted commas for the value to be set)

Can this be achieved?

This doesn't work either:

`$this->db->set('abc = IFNULL(`abc`, 0) + $value');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to add the third parameter to FALSe (unescaped value)

```
$this->db->set('abc', 'IFNULL(abc, 0) + $value', FALSE);
```

or maybe

```
$this->db->set('abc', 'IFNULL(abc, 0) + '.$value.'', FALSE);
```